# NSArray support like C++ (odd code example)

Tags: c++, iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I have been doing objective c for a couple years, my co-developer however has only just begun, but his virgin eyes found something that I hadnt even dreamed of.

He used an NSArray like a C++ pointer array

```
self.myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"object1",@"object2",@"object3",nil];
NSString *object1 = self.myArray[0];
NSString *object2 = self.myArray[1];
```

Now while this does actually work, I cant find reference to it.

I also have not found any examples of it in use.

Does anyone have any insight into why this works. Or can lead me to some documentation to the usage.

I had no idea that you could use the NSArray like an old c++ array ??

Comment: Note that you can also declare self.myArray= @[ @"object1",@"object2",@"object3"]; There is a similar syntax also for dictionaries and numbers.

Comment: I think this is something that Apple added to Objective-C along with array literals.

Comment: BTW Xcode can refactor code to the modern syntax

Comment: is there a quick "Refactor to new syntax" button or is that 6 months of work ?

Comment: It's an option under Edit->Refactor.

Comment: See Xcode's menu "Edit => Refactor"

Comment: Excellent. i am grateful there is a "StackOverflow" community. I gave all the votes I could for all of your collective help. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) link does show an example of access by index, even thought its not quite talking about that.. Im new to Objective C, so what is it that surprises you exactly?

Edit: You are right, this syntax appears to be a [recent change](http://www.globalnerdy.com/2012/09/23/objective-c-nsnumber-nsarray-nsdictionary-less-yak-shaving/) with XCode 4.5 - Scroll to about half way.

Comment: every example I have seen of it uses -[NSArray objectAtIndex:] i never even thought to use it like a regular array. I am wondering if its a legitimate use. or if it just "Happens" to be in the right order.

Comment: @VolureDarkAngel You are right, it is new, you can take a look at my edit

Comment: cool. Many thanks. I have checked it out. I was looking for some info on when or where this actually came from. And was surprised that it actually worked. Thanks again for the intel. Ill add that to my "A-OK" code list. Just freaks me out when a new ios guy comes up with something I have never seen.

Comment: It's called "Array Subscripting", for further reference.